# Error assigning multiple variable in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, variables, assign

I'm having trouble assigning multiple variables at one in PostgreSQL:

This didn't work

```
with temp_table as (select col1, col2 from another_table)
select into a, b col1, col2 from temp_table
```

Neither did this

```
with temp_table as (select col1, col2 from another_table)
select col1, col2 into a, b from temp_table
```

I got the following error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near ","

Edit: The same happened to the following:

```
select a, b into c, d from (values (1, 2), (3, 4)) as ttt (a, b)
```

Does this have something to do with the postgresql version?

Could you please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the assignment happening from within a function? `SELECT col1, col2 INTO a, b FROM another_table` is valid. Why do you need the CTE?

Comment: hi, no it doesn't. What do you mean by CTE?

Comment: Your `WITH` statement. CTE means common table expression. Is this assignment being done within a function? Are `a` and `b` declared?

Comment: no it doesn't happen within a function. I've added a small query to the original post, which yields the same error!

Comment: 2nd and 3rd queries work in plpgsql , check this link : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=e87b357811876d8d73823dd154d7c117

Comment: Yeah, the problem is your variables are not declared. Postgres doesn't know what `a` and `b` are. Kaushik just did it in an anonymous function. That is why I was asking about whether or not this is being done within a function.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the **complete** code of your function or procedure

Comment: Thanks! This was really confusing, because I tried assigning only 1 variable outside a function, and it worked ...